# What is NaN equivalent for int type in F#?

Tags: .net, f#, int, tryparse

In F# I can parse a float like this:

```
let tryParseFloat s =
    let ok,f = System.Double.TryParse s
    if ok then f else nan
```

and then

```
let parsed = tryParse "123.123"
match parsed with
| nan -> ignore parsed
| _ -> dostuff parsed
```

How can I achieve similar functionality with int?

Comment: `System.Int32.TryParse`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to represent an absence of a value in F#, using `option` is the way to do it. Doing that you make it abundantly clear through the type system that the value may or may not be there. So you should definitely use `int option` here.

I would strongly advise you to use a `float option` as well, instead of a NaN, for the same reason.

While NaN is a perfectly valid value for a float in .NET, it's sort of a dent in F# type system. In particular, `nan = nan` is false, and it doesn't play well with structural comparisons for complex F# types (like discriminated unions and records) that carry NaNs. You get errors that can be painful to track down. While it can be unavoidable if you get NaN's as result of numeric operations, you can do better than using them to represent absence of a value as well.

So follow @FuleSnabel's advice for `ints`, and use something like this for `floats`:

```
let tryParseFloat s =
    let ok, f = System.Double.TryParse s
    if ok then Some f else None
```

**Edit:** Actually, the code you posted doesn't quite work, in part because of the above.

```
 match parsed with
 | nan -> ignore parsed
 | _ -> dostuff parsed
```

Here you don't check for a NaN, you bind `parsed` to a value called `nan`, and the second case will never be hit (`warning FS0026: This rule will never be matched`).

A slightly better attempt would be something like this:

```
 match parsed with
 | f when f = nan -> ignore parsed
 | _ -> dostuff parsed
```

But here the first case will never be hit, because as I just wrote above, `f` will **never be equal** to `nan` (even when `parsed` is a `NaN`)

You need to use `Double.IsNaN` to check for NaNs:

```
 match parsed with
 | f when System.Double.IsNaN(f) -> ignore parsed
 | _ -> dostuff parsed
```

But it just shows that it wasn't a good idea in the first place.

**tl;dr:** NaNs are bad for you.

Comment: Be careful with "strongly advise". TryParse is [optimized](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/pull/335) even if one uses tuple expansion, but when one allocates an option explicitly - this is still an allocation and on hot paths (e.g. numeric code) should be avoided. Also, NaN is a part of IEEE standard, it should be treated specially in a general case. I upvote because you are right on this: "If you want to represent an absence of a value", but NaN is not an absence of value, it is some value which is "Not a Number". Also, stop treating F# as "not .NET", - it is!

Comment: @V.B.: if you're writing numeric code - sure, NaNs have a place there. Otherwise, they don't. Particularly, they're not a good way to model an absence of a value. Also, I'm painfully aware that F# is .NET, since things like this one do crop up and break the clean abstractions the language provides all the time ;)

Comment: @V.B.: Arguably, parsing a value is hardly "numeric code".

Comment: I had explicitly wrote that you are right about "absence of value". As per parsing, have a look at [Jil](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Jil), which is now parsing this my comment when I press Enter. They went a long way to optimize what a "sane person" would never do.

Answer (score 4):

`int` like types doesn't have a NaN value. Instead you can use `int option`. Maybe something like this:

```
let tryParseInt s =
  let ok,i = System.Int32.TryParse s
  if ok then Some i else None
```